# HttpErrorResponse %20 url Issue

Tags: angular, angularjs, http, frontend

I'm using **Angular** v15 on my **client** side and I'm trying to post product to my **API** but It's giving me a **404 HttpErrorResponse**. When I look the **url** that I'm trying to post with is not correct.

```
'https://localhost:7235/api/%20%20%20%20products'
```

It should be like

```
'https://localhost:7235/api/products'
```

I'm trying to figure out where am I doing wrong

My http-client service ;

```
    post<T>(requestParameter: Partial<RequestParameters>, body: Partial<T>): Observable<T> {
        let url: string = "";
    
        if (requestParameter.fullEndPoint)
          url = requestParameter.fullEndPoint;
        else
          url = `${this.url(requestParameter)}`
    
        return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, body, { headers: requestParameter.headers });
      }

export class RequestParameters {
  controller?: string;
  action?: string;

  headers?: HttpHeaders;
  baseUrl?: string;
  fullEndPoint?: string;
}
```

My product service ;

```
 create(product: Create_Product, successCallBack?: any) {
    this.httpClientService
      .post(
        {
          controller: 'products',
        },
        product
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        successCallBack();
      });
```

And I'm calling It here ;

```
create(
    name: HTMLInputElement,
    stock: HTMLInputElement,
    price: HTMLInputElement
  ) {
    const create_product: Create_Product = new Create_Product();
    create_product.name = name.value;
    create_product.stock = parseInt(stock.value);
    create_product.price = parseFloat(price.value);

        this.productService.create(create_product, () => {
  this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallAtom);
  this.alertify.message("The product has been successfully added.",{
    dismissOthers: true,
    messageType: AlertifyMessageType.Success,
    position: Position.TopRight
  });
```

Comment: What does this.url do?

Comment: It posts API the product entity for create operation

Comment: But can you show the code?